# Soap Web Service with Anypoint Studio (Mule 3.6.0)

Tags: web-services, parameters, mule-studio, payload

I am working on a mule studio application in which I am calling a soap web service

http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL

I have an HTTP:listener , SET PAYLOAD and WEB SERVICE between two DATAMAPPERS.

I want the service response writing " **localhost:8081/?CityName=Roma&CountryName=Italy** " but I don't know **how writte the value in Set Payload**.

I tried writing *#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.CityName, message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.CountryName]* but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the data in set payload as JSON String

{"city":"#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.CityName]","country":"#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.CountryName]"}

after this use datamapper to map it to webservice request